# IRS lost my paper return. Does this happen a lot?

Tags: united-states, irs, form-1040

I received yesterday a form letter saying IRS has no record of my (paper) tax return.
They did promptly cash the check that was in the same envelope, and show me as having paid them the money, but they don't know the details.
I have to promptly resend them my form (happily, I always save a copy of everything).

My question is, given news of all the problems at IRS last year, did they lose a lot of paper forms?  Part of me suspects an attempt to push people to filing online, which I don't want to do.  But it's probably just incompetence.

Also, I'm thinking of sending it via certified mail this time, but maybe that's pointless, since it wasn't lost in the USPS last time (since the check was cashed).

Comment: This exact thing happened to me: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59968776#59968776

Comment: My condolences. Hope we get this resolved too. My Uncle has same problem, https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/148848/irs-says-senior-is-entitled-to-credit-but-only-if-they-receive-his-2020-return

Comment: How long ago did you mail it? **IRS does not cash your check, a 'lockbox' bank does,** see https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/141983/irs-2020-refund-not-received and https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/136689/ , and it _normally_ takes weeks after that for IRS to transcribe a paper return; with COVID it's months.

Comment: No, they sent me a letter saying they don't have it, but they have my check (they show a credit in the amount of my check).  They lost the paperwork.